# How can I adjust this javascript code so an animation is activated whenever the mouse hovers over the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

So I used this code from Justin Aguilar's CSS3 Animation Cheat Sheet to activate an animation on a button when I hover over it:

```
<div id="object" class="pulse">
<script>
$('#animatedElement').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("pulse");
});
</script>
```

The problem is that the animation just continues even when I am no longer hovering over the button. What can I do to make a button animate every time a user hovers over it, but stop when they move the mouse away? Whenever I tried to tweak it with anything involving .stop, it just keeps the animation from playing at all.

I am new to coding and this has been a huge pain today, so any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript for that at all.
Use CSS selectors. #animatedElement:hover in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with one more solution

```js
$('#animatedElement').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass("pulse");
}).mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).removeClass("pulse");
});
```

```css
.pulse {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="animatedElement">Hover Me!!!</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

the `hover()` method accepts two callbacks: one for when the mouse enters the html element, and one for when it leaves.  Therefore, you could simply add another callback to your function to remove the "pulse" class.

```
$('#animatedElement').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass("pulse");
},
function(){
  $(this).removeClass("pulse");
});
```

Alternatively, you could just go with Alex's excellent answer.

Comment: I tried out this code and it just about worked. The only issue now is that it recognizes the area surrounding the button as part of the element. I am using Squarespace which creates a button block. I can see the outline of the block element, and I definitely see that it's larger than the actual button that I want to animate. Do you know if there is any way around that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to make an animation, for example, in this code:

```
.pulse {
    background: GREEN;
    border-radius: 6px
    transition-property: background, border-radius;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
}
.pulse:hover {
    background: BLACK;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

You have set in css the start properties for the element, and transition declaration, in this example i'm going to do a transition in the background and the radius properties when hover on a element with pulse class.